# Combine two Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas Series, `s1` and `s2` that I would like to combine.

```
s1 = pd.Series([2,5,5], index=['a','b','c'])
s2 = pd.Series([2,4,7], index=['a','b','d'])
```

This is the result I would like:

```
s3 = pd.Series([4,9,5,7], index=['a','b','c','d'])

a    4
b    9
c    5
d    7
dtype: int64
```

I've tried the `+` operator, `s1.append(s2)`, and `pd.join([s1,s2])` but these don't give the result I'm looking for.

Comment: How about s1.add(s2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like `add` will work here

```
s1.add(s2,fill_value=0)
Out[145]: 
a    4.0
b    9.0
c    5.0
d    7.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Numpy `np.add.at`

This is kind of ridiculous but I wanted to show something different

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

k, v = zip(*chain(*map(pd.Series.items, [s1, s2])))
i, r = pd.factorize(k)
out = np.zeros(len(r), dtype=int)
np.add.at(out, i, v)
pd.Series(out, r)

a    4
b    9
c    5
d    7
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is good but seems way lengthy when pandas DataFrame.add  is there :-)

Comment: @pygo hence the comment *ridiculous*.  I personally believe it serves to show how it could be done differently.  If people see these alternative answers, they may incorporate the knowledge and find better uses for it later.

Comment: of course that's good for ppls over SO for looking such logics, thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Just use pandas.Series.add

```
s3 = s1.add(s2, fill_value=0)

#result
a    4.0
b    9.0
c    5.0
d    7.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `add`

```
pd.concat((s1,s2), axis=1, sort=True).sum(1, min_count=1)
```

Output:

```
a    4.0
b    9.0
c    5.0
d    7.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple answer Directly from [pandas.Series.add](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) , you will get it from here

For you Use case here..

**First dataframe:**

```
>>> s1
a    2
b    4
c    5
dtype: int64
```

**Second Dataframe:**

```
>>> s2
a    2
b    4
d    7
dtype: int64
```

Simple `DataFrame.add` +  `fill_value`  which is explained in docs:

```
>>> s1.add(s2, fill_value=0)
a    4.0
b    8.0
c    5.0
d    7.0
dtype: float64
```

Document :

> fill_value : None or float value, default None
>
> Fill existing missing (NaN) values, and any new element needed for
>   successful DataFrame alignment, with this value before computation. If
>   data in both corresponding DataFrame locations is missing the result
>   will be missing

Comment: These are `Series` so the correct method is `pandas.Series.add`.  Also, this is addressed by @W-B

Comment: Thnx for pointing that out , link is just stand corrected , i Know its addressed by @W-B and Drew Nicolette but thought to link that with original docs while showing that for the use case here, i'm  firm believer in getting & putting the explanation and like that style because it helps newbies to understand under the hood :).